# How do i store the output of AWK as a variable to use in a SED command in a BASH script?

Tags: bash, sed, awk, pipe, stdout

I have used this to create a character string:

```
awk -F "|" 'NR==1 {print $2$4}' file
```

I now want to use this string to replace another string using SED, using this code, which i know works:

```
sed -i.bak 's/\(<remote>\).*\(<\/remote>\)/<remote> http:\/\/blabla\/'$var' <\/remote>/g' file2.xml
```

But what i can't figure out is how to save the output of the awk as $var first to use as an input for SED. can anyone help? thanks.

Comment: The above sed command will fail cryptically for various settings of `var`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do that, just use awk, e.g.:

```
awk -F'|' '
NR==FNR { if (NR==1) var = $2$4; next }
{ gsub(/<remote>.*<\/remote>/,"<remote> http://blabla/" var " </remote>"); print }
' file file2.xml > tmp && mv tmp file2.xml
```

With GNU awk you could make it more efficient but it won't make a noticeable difference unless your first file is huge:

```
awk -F'|' '
NR==FNR { var = $2$4; nextfile }
{ gsub(/<remote>.*<\/remote>/,"<remote> http://blabla/" var " </remote>"); print }
' file file2.xml > tmp && mv tmp file2.xml
```

wrt a comment I made in someone else's post, here's why you should us `-v var=val` instead of populating variables in the awk args list unless you need to do that to change initial values between files (not necessary with GNU awk courtesy of BEGINFILE):

Here's a script to add the values stored in 3 files to some initial seed value and print the result for each file and across all files (the seed is just added once to the total). file2 is empty:

```
$ cat file1
3
6
$ cat file2
$ cat file3
2
5
$ cat tst.awk                                
BEGIN {
    print "seed value =", seed

    for (i=1; i<ARGC; i++)
        subtotal[ARGV[i]] = seed

    total = seed
}

{
    subtotal[FILENAME] += $0
    total += $0
}

END {
    for (filename in subtotal)
        print "File", filename, "subtotal =", subtotal[filename]

    print "total =", total
}
$ 
$ awk -v seed=7 -f tst.awk file1 file2 file3
seed value = 7
File file1 subtotal = 16
File file2 subtotal = 7
File file3 subtotal = 14
total = 23
```

All makes sense right? Now lets move the setting of "seed" into the argument list:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk seed=7 file1 file2 file3          
seed value = 
File file1 subtotal = 9
File file2 subtotal = 
File file3 subtotal = 7
File seed=7 subtotal = 
total = 16
```

Note that the seed value is missing from the first print, the subtotals and total are wrong, and there's an output trying to print a value for a file named "seed=7".

It's all explicable and predictable once you know exactly what you're doing with awk but I bet it's pretty baffling to a newcomer so IMHO populating variables in the arg list should not be how we advise people to initialize their variables by default since it's got far less intuitive semantics than `-v variable=value`.

Comment: The first and second awk statements both do exactly what i asked. Thank you! I now need to do a bit more though; I want to read the lines of `file` and for each line do this action on their own unique `file.xml` which already exists and it's location is given by `$6` in `file`. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, any text processing is possible. Post a new question with your new requirements, sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 2):

```
var=$(awk -F "|" 'NR==1 {print $2$4}' file)
```

But its better you give us data and what to do with it.  This way we can make an awk or sed that does it all.

Edit:

```
var="test"
echo "https://blabla/bla/bla </remote>" | awk '{$NF="</"v">"}1' v="$var"
https://blabla/bla/bla </test>
```

This will replace the something with value of $var

Comment: That didn't quite work.... the SED no longer accepts the variable, when i had var=string before it had no problem. So what i need to do is replace the contents of this element: `<remote> https://blabla/bla/bla </remote>` with the combination of 2 fields delimited by a "|". I am new to stack so doing my best, also can't go into too much detail due to the content of the data. Thanks

Comment: IMHO you should only set variables in the awk arg list if they need to change between files and if you're going to set variables in the awk argument list, you should at least make sure the person you're replying to understands the negative impacts of doing it that way vs using `-v variable=value`.